# Unable to set schedule time accurately on 6.0 and above

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-alarms

I'm trying to make an app where it requires schedule time to be accurate. I need to reset the log(driver duty info) generated within app at a specific time.

I tried to use `setAlarm` but its not working accurately on 6.0 and above. As it should work without internet I can't go with `Push Notification.`I also tried to use `setAlarmClock` but it doesn't work accurate either.

I need `alarm` to be accurate for 1 hour and 24 hour

**Update**

**Log Alarm**

```
public static void startLogAlarm(Context ctx,long milliseconds) {

    final int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    // 1 Day = 86400 seconds = 86400000 milliseconds
    long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + milliseconds;

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, eLogReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(Utility.eLOG_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 3, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

       alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pi);

    } else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

       alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pi);

    } else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

    //  AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new  AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(timeInMillis, pi);
    //  alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pi);

        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pi);

    }
}

// Start Alarm
Utility.startLogAlarm(this, Constants.DAY_MILLISECONDS);

public class Constants {

   public static final long HOUR_MILLISECONDS = 3600000;
   public static final long DAY_MILLISECONDS = 86400000;
}
```

**Sensor Alarm**

```
 public static void startSensorAlarm(Context ctx, long timeInMillis) {

    final int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(Utility.SENSOR_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInMillis, pi);
    } else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInMillis, pi);
    } else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + timeInMillis, pi);

     //AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(System.currentTimeMillis()+timeInMillis, pi);
        alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pi);
    }

    showLog("Sensor Alarm Time", timeInMillis + "");
}
```

**Group Alarm**

```
 public static void startGroupAlarm(Context ctx) {

    final int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(Utility.GROUP_UPDATE_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 2, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + INTERVAL_EVERY_8_HOURS, pi);
    } else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + INTERVAL_EVERY_8_HOURS, pi);
    } else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + INTERVAL_EVERY_8_HOURS, pi);
    }

    Utility.showLog("Group Alarm", "Started");

}
```

**LogNoticeAlarm**

```
 public static void startLogNoticeAlarm(Context ctx, long milliseconds) {

    final int SDK_INT = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    // 1 Hour = 3600 seconds = 3600000 milliseconds
    long HourMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis() + milliseconds;

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, eLogNoticeReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(Utility.eLOG_NOTICE_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 4, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, HourMilliseconds, pi);
    } else if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= SDK_INT && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, HourMilliseconds, pi);
    } else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + milliseconds, pi);

     // AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(HourMilliseconds, pi); // alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pi);

    }

}
```

***I've been using total 4 alarms out of them 1 required to be schedule at every 5 minutes and rest are 1 hours, 8 hours and 24 hours. so is that sensor alarm( every 5 minutes) is causing the problem for other Alarm?***

Please suggest the best solution

**Note : All other questions on SO are not working.**

Comment: What behavior are you experiencing with `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`?  As long as your alarms are not within 15 minutes of each other, that should do an exact alarm to the second even through Doze mode.

Comment: how do you calculate initial milliseconds as well

Comment: How inaccurate are we talking? Have you tried with a different requestcode than 3, in case it's conflicting?

Comment: @NickCardoso No there is no conflict with request code. I've hardcoded milliseconds for an hour and a day

Comment: What happens in 6.0 and above?

Comment: I hope you already went through with 'setExactAndAllowWhileIdle' documentation.

Comment: You would not require help if your code was all working perfectly. Please show how you "hardcoded milliseconds for an hour and a day" and how you are sure "there is no conflict with request code". If you want a working answer don't be dismissive of things that help in problem determination

Comment: @NickCardoso I've updated code

Comment: Hey, you still haven't stated what is actually going wrong? Which alarm is not accurate, by how much? What is/isnt happening differently to what you expect?

Comment: I set all the alarm during login and keep the device aside for some hours. I don't see hourly/daily alarm executed. If device is awake for an hour it works with hourly and other alarm(5 minutes) remains `inexact` but I'm more concerned with daily and hourly alarm

Comment: All my alarms are in-exact but I want few of them(daily and hourly) to be exact to make my app work. @NickCardoso

Comment: Do you see a better solution to my problem? @NickCardoso

Comment: Did you see my comment on Neo's answer?

Comment: Yeah I saw but didnt got how it can fix? Can we make all the alarms exact including 5 minutes? If no then what are the possible solutions we can play with to make it more accurate.

Comment: What If i remove code for 5 min alarm and test? Do you think it can fix it?

Comment: I'll add an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several way you could address this problem.

Firstly pay attention to this (paraphrased) quote from the [Android Alarm Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

> Alarm Manager is intended to run your code at a specific time, even if your app is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use a Handler.

You can read more about the tradeoffs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html). That being said I'll answer on the basis of keeping all as alarms. Another quote from the same documentation mentions:

> Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups ... Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior.

This actually refers to [Doze Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html), which states:

> AlarmManager alarms (including setExact()) are deferred to the next maintenance window.

To steal Google's image from the same [documentation on dozing](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html):

[image: doze vizualization]

What this means to you is, if you have alarms close to eachother, the device will batch them in the next maintenance cycle but if you set 
`targetSdkVersion` lower, you have an easy fix to excluding the batching behaviour (*but at the cost of other compiled-in improvements*).

Presuming you actually stick with the Doze behaviour, switching to extending [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html?hl=ja) insted of regular `BroadCastReceiver` can help ensure you have time to respond to the `RTC_WAKEUP` Alarms.

You can also use more than one BroadcastReceiver so that Android handles them separately (rather than batching them to one per minute / maintenance). This would just mean the different pending intents get handled on different receivers:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
...
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver2.class); //a different receiver class
...
```

*I'm not clear from your code whether the eLogNotice receiver is an instance of the same receiver the other alarms are using.*

Comment: eLogNotice receiver has different receiver. In face 1 hour and 24 hours alarms have different receiver.

Comment: I'd say the first change to try is using Wakeful receives then as I've linked to. Small change to make

Comment: App is already live so we can't go for lower target version. Yes, I'll try with wakeful receiver shortly

Comment: It started to work but still its not accurate. Hourly Alarm remain accurate for 6 hours thereafter it slightly got delayed by 7 minutes, now it remains 7 minute delay every hour.

Comment: Alarms are getting executed but they are not accurate. can we make it accurate specially with 24 hr alarm?

Comment: I've marked your answer just because alarms are getting executed but it doesnt work accurate

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this one is causing problem due to alarm in every 5 min.So other alarm leads to failure because two alarm hits at the same time.

So my suggestion is set your other alarm time 1 or  2 min later/before(i.e. 8 hrs 2 min instead of 8 hrs ).

**Note:** 1 or 2 min should exactly decides by your ringtone duration.

Comment: Alarms only get merged if same receiver and id. Adding a second receiver for the 5min alarm can fix this